# The for loop and the get request

Tags: javascript, postgresql, vue.js, get-request

I'm trying to code an algorithm that for each data table retrieves the last data per column deposited in the table and sends it to an array. Then I want to display it on my application like this

[image]

So first I create my objects that compose my table for each data table:

```
    data () {
          return {
            tag_id: ['bts_d02c2b7d9098aaa2', 'bts_c077ffaa9098aaa2', 'bts_85zty3'],
           dessert:[];
    },
    methods:{
        CreateTable(){
        for(let i = 0; i < this.tag_id.length; i++){
          this.desserts.push(
            {
            name: this.tag_id[i],
            tension: 0,
            courant: 0,
            temperature: 0,
          },
          )
        }
      },
}
```

here it works.

Then, in a for loop I want that for each object of my table I fetch the last data and send it in the object that corresponds to it in the table:

```
getDatafor(){
        for(let i = 0; i < this.desserts.length; i++){
          this.val_ia = i;
          this.getAllData();
        }
      },

async getAllData() {
        console.log('val_ia is ' + this.val_ia)
                const tag_id_name = encodeURIComponent(this.tag_id[this.val_ia]);
                const url = this.$api.getRESTApiUri() + `/all/last_id/${tag_id_name}`;
                return fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then((result) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log("datasend")
            this.desserts[this.val_ia].tension = data[0].adc_v/100
            this.desserts[this.val_ia].courant = data[0].adc_i;
            this.desserts[this.val_ia].temperature = data[0].temperature/100;
            })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
           
});
    },
```

Only with this code the data are sent only when i == datasets.length-1. (imax)

Functions are called like this :

```
mounted(){
        this.CreateTable();
        setInterval(this.getDatafor, 4000)
    },
```

with consoles.log it does this:

[image]

I want it to be this :

val_ia is 0

datasend

val_ia is 1

datasend

val_ia is 2

datasend

I don't understand why the data are not sent each time we pass in the getAllData() function in a logical way

Answer (score 0):

async/await functions :

```
async getDatafor(){
            for(let i = 0; i < this.desserts.length; i++){
              this.val_ia = i;
              await Promise.all([this.getAllData()]);
            }
          },
```